# How do you override the default angular testbed html template?

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

How do I override the default angular testbed html template.
Currently it defaults to this below

```
 <div id="root0" _nghost-a-c16="" ng-version="10.2.5"></div>
```

I would like to add a custom class name or a make it an html page.

```
<div id="root0" class="myTestClass" _nghost-a-c16="" ng-version="10.2.5">
<!-- I want this custom class -->

</div>

or

<container id="root0" class="myTestClass" _nghost-a-c16="" ng-version="10.2.5">
<!-- I want this custom element -->

</container>
```

Here is my very basic testing code.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        RouterTestingModule
      ],
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  fit('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    console.log('fixture', fixture.debugElement);
    const app = fixture.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the element is present, you can probably do `document.querySelector('[ng-version]').classList.add('myTestClass');`.

That being said, it might be strange to do that and you can maybe get a handle on the element by just doing `const element = document.querySelector('[ng-version']);`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I need to add it using the testbed